# Hyperledger Fabric Private data using SDK nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I tried to instantiate the chain-code with 'collections-config' according the tutorial provided.

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-private-data.html

But its not working after instantiated. At the time of invoke chain code I'm getting error

> ERRO 004 Failed to get collection state
>           /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/handler.go:324
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.(*ChaincodeStub).GetPrivateData
>           /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:450
>   main.(*TravelandTransport).addCard
>           /chaincode/input/src/github.com/example_cc/go/chaincode.go:73 main.(*TravelandTransport).Invoke
>           /chaincode/input/src/github.com/example_cc/go/chaincode.go:41 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.(*Handler).handleTransaction.func1
>           /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/handler.go:273
>   runtime.goexit
>           /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361

It is missing the file for the collection configuration.

Here is the request object and the code

```
var request = {
        targets: peers,
        chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
        chaincodeType: chaincodeType,
        chaincodeVersion: chaincodeVersion,
        args: args,
        txId: tx_id,
        'collections-config': collectionsConfigPath
    };

    if (functionName)
        request.fcn = functionName;

    let results = await channel.sendInstantiateProposal(request, 200000);
```

I also tried all the version of fabric-client from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0-snapshot.18